# How to have write access to a recently formatted drive by default?

Tags: gparted, format, mass-storage

Whenever I format a drive using gparted, the drive becomes owned by root user by default, and I cannot write to it. To solve this, I have to open file manager as root, and assign myself read/write permissions.

How to avoid this hassle so that I can have write permissions right after formatting, without changing settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To solve this, I have to open file manager as root, and assign myself read/write permissions.

Not really. After formatting you should do:

```
sudo chown -r $USER:$USER /path/to/drive
```

logged in as that user (so from a $-prompt, not a # prompt). I assume here $USER is the admin user, otherwise use the actual username of who needs to own the drive.

Be careful with the /path/to/drive/. If you do this with "." from the root or from another path then the device you will kill your system.

> without changing settings?

Nope. We take security seriously ;) A device formatted by root will be owned by root and the admin will then need to assign the device to a user. Yes, I agree that this is a bit more effort from a user if he is both admin and user but it is considered the most secure with the least amount of effort from the user.

Comment: Am I supposed to write "$USER" in the command, or my actual username?

Comment: $USER will be interpreted as the current user. So you can use that command exactly as written

Comment: *A device formatted by root will be owned by root and the admin will then need to assign the device to a user* - Is there a way to get the drive formatted by an user instead?